# Firebase functions returns: Authorization is required for access to this proxy

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've created a nodejs REST API to read, write and delete the data in firebase cloud store. The code is also hosted in firebase functions.
Some times the function returns :

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Authorization Required</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
    <H1>Authorization Required</H1>
    <HR>
    <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
    <HR>
    <!-- default "Authorization Required" response (401) -->
</BODY>
```

However if I open browser and open console.firebase.google.com and try to request the same api, it works as I've coded.

I've tried disabling SSL certificate verification, adding firebase login as basic auth, none worked.

The postman web request is as below(as C# code):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://myapplication.firebaseapp.com/getData/1234567");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The code which consumes the REST API is written in C#.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.